# Spring JPA Update Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to update my user entity and I have an error that comes to mind:
ERROR: A NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint of the "id" column Detail: The failed row contains (null, 1, 1)

The problem surely stems from my relationship between user and profile which is n-n

```
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer id;

private Integer fixe;

private Boolean deleted;

private Boolean actif;

private String email;

private Integer mobile;

private String motDePasse;

private String nom;

private String prenom;

@ManyToMany
private List<Profil> profils = new ArrayList<Profil>();

public Utilisateur() {
}
}

public class Profil implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer id;

private String codeProfil;

private String libelleProfil;

@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany
private List<MenuAction> menuActions = new ArrayList<MenuAction>();

public Profil() {
}
}
```

Comment: kindly provide the error stack in English, not in your native language.

Comment: you don't have any `User` entity defined here.

Comment: User = Utilisateur

Answer (score 0):

How you generate value for your id?
Seems you need some way to generate value for you ID.
For example, use `@GeneratedValue`, like:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
```

Comment: My problem is that I need a relationship entity between the two tables. See my other post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882726/return-information-relation-many-to-many