# Return information relation many-to-many

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, entity

I have a manytomany relationship between my user table and profile. So I created a entity UserProfile

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer id;

private String email;
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

public User() {
}

  GETTER / SETTER
}


public class Profile implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer id;

private String libelleProfile;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

GETTER / SETTER
}

public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idProfile")
private Profile profile;
}
```

When I do a find to retrieve my user’s information, he doesn’t get me his profile.

Here is the flow json turned

{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "userEmail",
}

That’s how I get my entity back :

```
//In my service
userRepository.findByEmail(email);

public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, 
Integer>{
   User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: Could you show some more code on how you retrieve the entity?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Can you show the `Utilisateur` entity?

Comment: Sorry, Utilisateur = User. I'm edited my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonManagedReference vs JsonBackReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319358/jsonmanagedreference-vs-jsonbackreference)

Comment: What is the best solution

Comment: Help me. It is very urgent

Comment: Help me. It is very important to me